# Build and Split a 2D array with dtype=Objects

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, inverse

I'm creating a matrix of order [NBxNB] where each element is another matrix of order [3x3], and all the elements inside these matrices are complex numbers.
These [3x3] matrices are built with some FOR loops and must be positioned on specific positions on the [NBxNB] matrix. After all the [3x3] are correct positioned,
I need to transform the blocks on a single [3NBx3NB] matrix, evaluate the inverse matrix and divide the inverse [3NBx3NB] matrix into the same [NBxNB] structure with the [3x3] submatrices.

I need this division because I want to be able to select the submatrices individualy to perform a few calculations after the inversion.

The main procedure to build the matrix and inverse is shown below, with some zero data just to exemplify the code.

```
#This is the function to divide the inverse in blocks - Got here on StackOverflow but don't remeber from which post...
def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):
    h, w = arr.shape
    assert h % nrows == 0, "{} rows is not evenly divisble by {}".format(h, nrows)
    assert w % ncols == 0, "{} cols is not evenly divisble by {}".format(w, ncols)
    return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
               .swapaxes(1,2)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))

Y = np.zeros([NB,NB], dtype=object)

for i in range(NB):
    for j in range(NB):
        Y[i][j] = np.zeros([3,3])
        Y[j][i] = np.zeros([3,3])
        
AUX = np.zeros(NB, dtype=object)
for i in range(NB):
    AUX[i] = np.vstack(Y[:,i]).astype(complex)

T = np.hstack(AUX).astype(complex) 
X = np.linalg.inv(T)
Z = blockshaped(X,3,3)
```

This code is working fine but I was figuring if there is a more 'pythonic way' of doing so.

Comment: Why not start with a `Y=np.zeros((NB, NB, 3, 3), dtype=complex)`, or even `Y=np.zeros((3,NB,3,NB), dtype=complex)`.  Indexing of either is equally easy.  The 2nd can be reshaped with `Y.reshape((3*NB, 3*NB))`.  You can also switch between the two with `Y.tranpose((2,0,3,1))`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll try it here

Comment: @hpaulj This `Y=np.zeros((NB, NB, 3, 3), dtype=complex)` works fine, but the reshape method doesn't work with it in the way I expect. It is putting all the elements from the [3x3] matrices in front of each other, and not taking only the first from each matrix. Could help me with this?

Comment: You'll need to transpose, before further reshape.